# NHibernate - Fluent auto mapping - Stateless batch insert - Many to Many data not inserting

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, batch-processing

I am trying to use NHibernate stateless batch insert. I am using HiLo to generate primary keys. I am importing large set of data from excel. While inserting many to many tables data is not inserting. 
Lets say, following is my model,

```
[IsModel]
    public class Debtor : User
    {
        public virtual IList<DebtorDocument> DebtorDocuments { get; set; }
    }
```

Data is inserting correctly in Debtor,User and DebtorDocument tables. But, no data is inserting in DebtorDocumentsToUser many to many table.

anyone have clue what may be the reason! Searching through Google i have found an example where a model is created for many to many relation along with main models. Do i have to do that?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to help resolve your issue.  I would look at your cascade setup first off.  : http://ayende.com/blog/1890/nhibernate-cascades-the-different-between-all-all-delete-orphans-and-save-update

Comment: I have used fluent nhibernate auto mapping facility. So, there is no Class-map class for every model. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: anybody has any idea. please help. i need it very urgently. will be very apperciated